# Search for an element immediately

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I want to search for an element in an android application page which has a count down animation, so the searching for the element does not finish until the count down ends.
Is there any way Appium does not wait and return immediate results?

Answer (score 0):

Use threading while the one counts down other can help with the search and when the countdown ends the other thread can kill the searching thread.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your answer?